# In p2pool mining, what stops a block finder from stealing a block?

Tags: mining-pools

With a centralized pool, a miner uses the server's block template and since he doesn't know the whole block constructed by server, he cannot steal it. Now with decentralized p2pool mining, what stops him from doing that?

I read here (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/P2Pool), but it doesn't explain why he can't.

> He can NOT redirect the payout to himself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In p2pool mining, what stops a block finder from stealing a block?

The miner is doing work on an honest template so they still get rewarded even if the side chain share (block) isn't valid for the main chain.

If they edited the miner tx (to "steal" it) *after* doing the work, it would change the block template and thus invalidate the result (the hash would change), and if they edited the miner tx *before* doing the work, they couldn't submit as a valid share to the side-chain.